# jQuery - execute function before proceeding

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

How can I stop executing function till another function is done?

```
$('#div').load( 'sub.html', function() {

    //Do this once done loading the sub.html file
    setTimeout(function() { 

        //Run SomeFunction(); before doing anyhing else
        $('#tabsWrapper').removeClass('ajaxLoading');
        $('#tabsWrapper #loaderDiv').fadeIn(500);

    } , 1000);

});
```

I want to make sure `SomeFunction()` is done before doing `$('#tabsWrapper').removeClass('ajaxLoading');` etc..

Any suggestion how can I achieve that? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: return value from SomeFunction and see if it's done, could you a loop until value is returned.

Comment: use a callback on .load. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688958/jquery-load-callback-scrolling-css-overflow, i believe that will work.

Comment: seems to be quite normal flow of the script. is simeFunction doesnt have anything like  `ajax` it will run the way you require it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return some value from your `SomeFunction()` and put in condition like this:

```
var result = null; // important to put it here eg before setTimeout

//Do this once done loading the sub.html file
setTimeout(function() { 

    result = SomeFunction();

    if (result === 'whatever that function returns') {
      $('#tabsWrapper').removeClass('ajaxLoading');
      $('#tabsWrapper #loaderDiv').fadeIn(500);
    }

} , 1000);
```

A better approach would be using self-invoking anonymous function something like this:

```
(function foo(){
   doStuff;

   setTimeout(foo, 500);

})()
```

[Here `setTimeout` will only trigger when `doStuff` is finished.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472528/javascript-jquery-closure-function-syntax)

Comment: The quastion is - if the `SomeFunction()` is not done before `if statement` will it be skipped than? I want to make sure the order of executing is maintained.

Comment: @NewUser: See the later approach :)

Comment: Nearly there. Where do I put the code to be exectuted once `doStuff();` is done? Before or after `setTimeout`, or maybe inside? but how?:)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#div').load( 'sub.html', function(response, status) {

     if(status=="success"){
          //do your stuff here ..its loaded
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the callback method.

Please refer to the JQuery [API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)